# Complex shapes as buttons/links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsf

I am working on a java/jsf based web application and am wondering what, if any, technologies would allow me to define complex shapes as clickable buttons or links. At the moment all i can do is divide a picture to smaller transparent pics and make those as links, but you will be able to click whole picture area, even that that is transparent.

For example say i have a picture of a human and i want to make its leg clickable. The clickable area should match that of a leg silhouette in that picture. How would one go to achieve that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: [**svg**](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) - [**area**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) example that you can click specific parts of images after you define their coordinates.

HTML

```
<img src="img.png" width="145" height="126" usemap="#picture-map">

<map name="picture-map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Leg" href="legs.htm">
</map>
```

Now you can click and get sent to another page, and if you want you could probably bind it to a JS function.

Good luck